The certificate could not be installed on the domain “example.com”. Unknown error
I've received an old domain, but it's SSL certificate has expired. I'm trying to install a new, free certificate issued by Cloudflare. Things appear to have gone well in Cloudflare, as it claims I'm protected. However, over in cPanel, I'm unable to install the certificate. The domain, CRT, and Key appear to be correct, as I just copied and pasted what Cloudflare gave me, but after trying to install, it gives the following error:

The certificate could not be installed on the domain “example.com”.
unknown error

In the cPanel "General information" sidebar, it still says I have no valid certificate.
Additionally, the following message always shows up under the "Install an SSL Website" header, and since I'm a beginner I'm not completely sure if it's an issue:

Note: You don’t have a dedicated IP address. Browsers that were released before 2013 may not support SNI. Because of this, users may see false security warnings when they visit your SSL-secured websites.

The nameservers have been changed to the ones Cloudflare provided. I've deleted previous certificates, generated new ones, but it still gives the same "unknown error" after trying to install.

It's fixed, but I'll write it down in case someone else finds themselves with this same problem.
I had provided the CRT and KEY as requested, but the CA area claimed that sometimes the CA doesn't always need to be supplied and that cPanel could fetch it during installation. Since the Cloudflare Origin Certificate generator area didn't visibly provide a CA, I assumed that it would take care of itself. It didn't.
After a long chat with support, I found the CA in the Cloudflare documentation at:

SSL/TLS > Origin server > Origin CA certificates > Additional details >
Cloudflare Origin CA root certificate.

I downloaded one of the two offered and, according to support, you just need to open it with the Notes app and copy it's contents to the CABUNDLE field when filling out the CRT and KEY.
I tested it with another domain and it works.
